# Mysql query : date_format and sprintf()

Tags: php, mysql, printf, date-format

I want to use sprintf() along with date_format in a MySQL query.

Here is query:

```
mysql_select_db($database_exdb, $expdb);
$query_eventeditrs = sprintf("SELECT eventid, groupid, title, DATE_FORMAT(dateofevent, '%W, %M %d, %Y'), timeofevent, location, details, presenter, bio FROM events WHERE eventid = %s", GetSQLValueString($colname_eventeditrs, "int"));
```

I am getting error that :

```
“Warning: sprintf() [fun
ction.sprintf]: Too few arguments. Query was Empty”
```

Plz help

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have to escape the date format string with extra %'s, try this:

```
sprintf("SELECT eventid, groupid, title, 
DATE_FORMAT(dateofevent, '%%W, %%M %%d, %%Y'), 
ti meofevent, location, details, presenter, bio 
FROM events 
WHERE eventid = %s", GetSQLValueString($colname_eventeditrs, "int"));
```

Comment: how do you know that the OP wants **those** values escaped?

Comment: @Neal DATE_FORMAT format param uses %'s to signify date types.

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually run the query using mysql_query() see http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Comment: this has nothing to do with `mysql_query`

Answer (score 0):

In the sprintf string you have:

```
"SELECT eventid, groupid, title, DATE_FORMAT(dateofevent, '%W, %M %d, %Y'), 
      timeofevent, location, details, presenter, 
       bio FROM events WHERE eventid = %s"
```

Which has `5` inputs, but you only put in **one** (`GetSQLValueString($colname_eventeditrs, "int")`), put in 4 more and you should be golden (or as said below in the comments, escape 4 of the inputs and that should also work)